# Better theorem body fonts

Tags: fonts, theorems

I am trying to set a good font for theorem body using `\newtheoremstyle`.

```
\newtheoremstyle{cooltheorem}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% measure of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {. ---}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
```

With `\itshape` the font is a little sharp and pointy
[image]

I am looking for something rounder. Something like this:
[image]

I tried tweaking the body font option in my theorem style. But I couldn't get it as I wanted.
Do you guys know some good fonts?

It would be nice to make the theorem notes [Authors ...] have normal fonts instead of italics.

I am using the document class MastersDoctoralThesis from  https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Tex Engine : pdfTeX (`pdflatex`)

For the rest of the document, I use palatino font from `{mathpazo}`

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, which TeX engine you use, and which fonts you load.

Comment: @Mico I am using MastersDoctoralThesis class (link in the question), I use `pdflatex` and mathpazo font for the rest of my document.

Comment: @SeverusTux That's italic Palatino: when you use Palatino for the text font, the italic font is taken from the same typeface. If you don't like the italic, don't use that typeface (that is, remove `\usepackage{mathpazo}`).

Comment: @egreg, I like the Palatino font for the rest of my document. Is there a way to disable it only for theorem environment?

Comment: @SeverusTux Mixing different serif typefaces? Sorry, that's not my idea of good typography.

Comment: @egreg, I am okay with compromising on such holiness. In my opinion, It would look better. Please let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: @SeverusTux Sorry. You'd end up with variables in Palatino Italic and words in some other italic font: nothing that I'd even attempt to do.

Answer (score 2):

It honestly sounds as if you want to choose a different text font and a different math font to go along with it.  Any answer is going to be a matter of opinion.  However, I’ll try to answer the question you asked.

The package you’re using, `mathpazo`, is a clone of Hermann Zapf’s Palatino, with additional math symbols by Young Ryu.  It’s a matter of opinion, but there are two other fonts by Zapf that you might try out.

One is his sans-serif typeface Optima.  There’s a clone of it available *gratis*, as URW Classico, [through the `getnonfreefonts` script.](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/)  You would use it with `mathpazo` (or its successor `newpxmath`) by loading the `classico` package that script installs, or in the modern toolchain, load it through `fontspec` with `\setsansfont{URW Classico}[Scale=MatchLowercase]`.  Either way, you would then switch to it with `\sffamily`.

Another is to use his math font, AMS Euler, for your math variables, with symbols and text based on Palatino.  There is a classic package for this, `eulerpx`, which you would load instead of `mathpazo`.  In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you would need to download the OpenType [Neo Euler font](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) and load symbols from it on top of Asana Math (which is based on `mathpazo`) or perhaps TeX Gyre Pagella Math:

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0] % Or Palatino, Palatino Linotype, etc.
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}.
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal,
                    bfcal},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
```

There has been at least one attempt to make a text font based on AMS Euler, spaced for body text rather than math: [Aref Ruqaa.](https://github.com/alif-type/aref-ruqaa)